# Kedro can not find SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, pymssql, kedro

I have these two datasets defined:

```
flp_test_query:
  type: pandas.SQLQueryDataSet
  credentials: dw_dev_credentials
  sql: select numero from dwdb.dwschema.flp_tst
  load_args:
    index_col: [numero]

flp_test:
  type: pandas.SQLTableDataSet
  credentials: dw_dev_credentials
  table_name: flp_tst
  load_args:
    index_col: ['numero']
    columns: ['numero']
  save_args:
    if_exists: 'append'
```

However, I only manged to get `flp_test_query` working, as when I try to access `flp_tst` I get this error:

> ValueError: Table flp_tst not found

I did try to define table name as `table_name: dwschema.flp_tst` and `table_name: dwdb.dwschema.flp_tst` but all trew the same error. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the actual name of the database, schema, and table?  And in the query you have `flp_tst` but in the second one you have `flp_test`.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft hey, I updated the question, sorry for the typos. db=dwdb, schema=dwschema, table=flp_tst

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro.extras.datasets.pandas.SQLTableDataSet.html) it looks like you can specify the schema in `load_args`, eg

```
  load_args:
    index_col: ['numero']
    columns: ['numero']
    schema: 'dwschema'
```

or

```
load_args = {"schema","dwschema"}
data_set = SQLTableDataSet(table_name=table_name,
                           credentials=credentials,
                            load_args=load_args)
```